# Android with Kotlin: Is there a way to find out the metadata (position) of the currently played song of an other app?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, metadata, spotify

I'm trying to write an app as a hobby for which it would be necessary to find out the song currently playing on the phone from another app (e.g. Spotify). But most of all I would need the current position in the song. 
I already found out that this can be done in Spotify and other apps via broadcast listener, but this option has to be activated suboptimally with Spotify first and with other apps I don't get any position, only meta data like artist, song length, song name, etc. 
I thought about the fact that Bluetooth radios can receive the current position, no matter from which app, but I don't know if this could be intercepted or if it could be accessed in the smartphone in some other way.

Or another possibility would be to read the current position from the notification in the Android status bar. But then I wouldn't know if or how that works.

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't arbitrarily access the data of another app. It is possible to communicate with apps by means of `Intent`s, if the app in question supports that.

For Spotify in particular, they publish an [Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/) which you can use from your own app to communicate with the Spotify app:

> The Spotify SDK allows your application to interact with the Spotify app running in the background as a service. The capabilities of this API include getting metadata for the currently playing track and context, issuing basic playback commands and initiating playback of tracks.